# django-filer - AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute '_inherited'

Tags: django, django-filer

I'm trying to install django-filer. But when I run `manage.py migrate` I get **AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute '_inherited'**. I don't know what that means. (I started this project with Heroku starter template https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template)

I initially thought that perhaps I forgot to install JPEG and ZLIB, but to my understanding they are default since Pillow 3.0.

```
$ pip freeze
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.10.4
django-filer==1.2.5
django-mptt==0.8.7
django-polymorphic==1.0.2
easy-thumbnails==2.3
gunicorn==19.6.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
whitenoise==3.2
Pillow==4.0.0
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'filer',
    'mptt',
     ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-filer 1.2.5 is not working under Django 1.10

They are working on the 1.2.6 version which has support for Django 1.10

https://github.com/divio/django-filer/milestone/20?closed=1

This is the specific issue https://github.com/divio/django-filer/issues/899

Comment: Argh okay, I guess I better revert back to Dango 1.9

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.10 you should use `django-polymorphic==1.3.1` as written in django-filter "Installation and Configuration" guide. It helped me to get django-filter work with Django 1.10 version.